# General Programming: How to implement model logic in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am currently trying to figure out how to properly implement the the MVC principle. Lets take for example a simple blog. I have a database that contains two tables: Blogs and comments. The blogs table consists of fields like a title, content, date, etc. Comments contain an autorname, a date, content, stuff like that.

Lets start with the easier items. I have a couple of views. Like:

- Write / edit blog item
- Display a blog item
- Display a summary page (e.g. recent blogs, popular topics, etc)
- etc

The controllers are also quite clear to me:

- Admin controller (transfers blog items to the write / edit views or sends them back)
- Blog controller (transfers blog items to the blog views, like the summary page or the page where just one is displayed. This also retrieves the comments)
- Comment controller (transfers data from the comment creation / deletion views)

But then comes the models. I really don't know how I should implement these. The Zend Framework quickstart page recommends a pretty small model with only private properties and getters and setters for the specific item. They recommend doing the database logic in a Mapper.

But here's my question. Let's say I want to fetch the most recent blog items. How would you implement this? Where would you write the function fetchRecentItems()? In the mapper? It seems that this should contain only basic CRUD statements. In another model, like BlogService? In the controller?

Can someone help me out here? I would love to see a quick pseudo-code example.

(I tried to summarize my knowledge to make my thinking process a little bit more clear. If I understood something wrong, please correct me. Thanks!)

Comment: You might be interested in reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design . Think of the "(domain) model" as the "language" of your domain (blogging system in your example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends how far you want to go with it really. Personally I would use a Service class, interacting with mapper classes, called from the controller. So your class might look something like:

```
class Yourapp_Service_Blog
{
    protected $_mapper;

    public function setMapper($mapper)
    {
        $this->_mapper = $mapper; 

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMapper()
    {
        return $this->_mapper;
    }

    public function fetchRecentItems($items)
    {
        $select = $this->getMapper()->getDbTable()->select();
        $select->order('createdAt DESC')
               ->limit($numItems);

        return $this->getMapper()->fetchAll($select);
    }
}
```

so then in your controller:

```
class BlogController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $service = new Yourapp_Service_Blog();
        $service->setMapper(new Yourapp_Model_GuestbookMapper());

        $this->view->posts = $service->fetchRecentItems(6);
    }
}
```

this starts to look like a lot of code to do a simple thing, but when you start seeing common elements between the classes you can refactor a bit to improve things. E.g. if you have multiple service classes that look like this you can move the get/set mapper functions into a base service class that they extend. You could add some logic to the getMapper() function that would work out what the correct mapper is based on the class name if one hasn't been supplied, saving you having to pass it in each time.

There isn't a 'right' answer here though, these patterns exist as solutions to common programming problems. Use as many or as few of them as you feel is appropriate for your app.

Comment: That looks awesome, and it really makes sense to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with the idea of a service layer, although it really depends on what works for you.

Our approach is to use such a layer as essentially a facade for the nuts and bolts underneath - it describes our application API in a way that makes sense to people who have to code against it.  Coding against this API hides the user from the things they're not concerned about, such as data storage and retrieval.

What we've found nice about this approach is that it makes sense semantically, correct separation of concerns keeps controllers thin and ensures portability of the model (not that I've ever had to make use of that, but who knows), it's easy to test against, it's scalable - we can easily build other layers on top (e.g. web services) etc. etc.

I hear where you're coming from as I was there not too long ago.  For a long time I was confused about how to implement the model with Zend Framework.  I was looking for a convention or someone to describe how it should be done.

What I've learnt over time is that there is no correct answer, and this is where ZF has got it absolutely spot on.  It just doesn't make sense to prescribe a mechanism when there's no "one size fits all" approach.

In summary, there is no "proper" way to implement the model.  As I say, I think it's just about finding something that is sensible for your own situation.

My advice is to Google for "Zend Framework Service Layer" and read up as much as you can on that - I think that might be of interest to you.  A lot of the time you'll end up back at Stack Overflow, but generally there are links out to good blog posts and articles too.

Good luck.

Comment: I have implemented a service layer and have seen the advantages. In my case, this was exactly the answer I was looking for, and I absolutely agree with you. It separates all the major components, but it still gives me all the possibilities to have them talk to each other. You might be right that there's no one answer, and that that's just the power of ZF, but that's also what makes it so confusing. I guess I still have to find that out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't only one way of developing a MVC app. In general there are lots of different approaches on what controllers, views and models are and should be or do.

I guess a good idea is to look how others did it.

Have a look at CakePHP: 
[Models](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1000/Models) /
[Views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1078/Views) /
[Controllers](http://book.cakephp.org/view/955/Controllers)

In general the controller puts data in a model (or creates a model), which the view uses to render the page.